# Why does Omniauth redirect to /auth/failure and not /auth/:provider/failure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

everything is in the title.

Do you know why omniauth redirects to /auth/failure in case of a failure for every strategy by default ?
It would be so much easier to customize errors pages depending on the strategy if it was by default /auth/:provider/failure.

What do you think ?

---

https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/588

Answer (score 0):

You could, referring to [this](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/pull/592) pull request do following in OmniauthCallbacksController#failure

```
strategy = params['strategy']
```